# Error with Facebook sdk in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I try to integrate Facebook sdk in swift but i got the error, anyone please help me how can i fix it ? Thanks so much for your helping

[here is image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DNbZ.png)

[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ9fg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Bolt framework to your Xcode project. For some reason the Facebook quick start guide for iOS doesn't say that anymore. Just drag & drop Bolt from your downloaded facebook SDK into XCode like FBSDKCoreKit etc.

[image]

Comment: Hi @ThànhTrungNguyễn that's awesome! I am glad I could help. Please mark my answer as correct :) (green check image)

Comment: i checked it, sorry about that because i'm new member

Comment: @ThànhTrungNguyễn it's all good :) Thanks! I hope you enjoy it here